# How to access a webservice using .wsdl file

Tags: web-services, wsdl

I need to consume a Webservice written in pearl in my .net Windows Application. I have been given a .wsdl file.

Please let me know how can i use that Web service in my Application using that .wsdl file.

Answer (score 1):

Use "Add Service Reference" in Visual Studio. Point it to the WSDL file on disk. That works as well as using a URL.

See "[How to Consume a Web Service](http://johnwsaundersiii.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!600A2BE4A82EA0A6!790.entry)".